# Adding Code Style Naming for Local Variables or Method Parameters - C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to add some Naming Rules in Visual Studio for C# language. Everything is OK.

for example I can add this rule:

> Property -> PascalCase -> Error

Which means all properties should be in pascal case mode and if not the IDE will give me error to fix it.

The Naming Menu can access in this way:

> Tools -> Options... -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Naming

There is a PROBLEM, I can not add rules for local variables or method parameters. I searched specification section but nothing.

[image]

Is this possible to add naming rules for variables? if yes, How?

Comment: For local variables, IIRC, you can use Manage Specifications, add one (green cross), select `local` on symbol (kind?) and match it with Accessibility->local. Give a name to the style and then you can add a new specification, assigning Pascal Case (or your own definition) to the Required style. For method parameters, the Symbol kind should be `parameter` or `type parameter` (or both).

Comment: @Jimi on my side there is no `local` option in symbol kinds section. The problem starts here :)

Comment: What is the Visual Studio version you're dealing with?

Comment: @Jimi the 2017 version

Comment: @Jimi The Enterprise one

Comment: (In `c#->Code Style->Naming`) Have you clicked the green cross button you find in the panel that appears after you have clicked the `Manage specifications` button? It's usually there. Anyway, see this [.NET naming conventions for EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-naming-conventions?view=vs-2017). You can "code" it. And this one: [Create portable, custom editor settings with EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2017)

Comment: @Jimi yes man, I clicked `Manage specifications` button, but in my list there is no local or type-parameter in symbol kinds list view and I do not know why. So as you suggested I think I should try creating an `EditorConfig`.

Comment: It's not in the `ListView`. It's in the `CheckedListBox` you can access using the green cross button there, below the ListView..

Comment: @Jimi I have attached an image so as you can see there is no `local` on my side

Comment: Yep, I see it. I have no idea why you are missing some settings (both in the left and right panels). I'll see to find a machine that has the Enterprise edition on to check this out (not today). But it seems nonsensical, unless someone has tampered with it (maybe you're too strict in your specifications :).

Comment: I am having a similar problem in 2019 - 'local' appears under Symbol Kinds, and also under Accessibilities, but no matter what I do I can't create a rule that will activate on a variable (or a const variable). Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For some strange reason, setting "local" in the Visual Studio (2019) Menu does not work.

However, it works perfectly for me to simply put the exact same setup into .editorconfig :

```
# C# files
[*.cs]

#### Naming styles ####

# Naming rules

dotnet_naming_rule.test_should_be_pascal_case.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.test_should_be_pascal_case.symbols = test
dotnet_naming_rule.test_should_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case

# Symbol specifications

dotnet_naming_symbols.test.applicable_kinds = local
dotnet_naming_symbols.test.applicable_accessibilities = local
dotnet_naming_symbols.test.required_modifiers = 

# Naming styles

dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.required_suffix = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.word_separator = 
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.capitalization = pascal_case
```

Just put the file into your solution's root directory.

It's also possible to *generate* such a file from the very same menu:

1. Set up your desired Naming styles in the Menu
2. Exit the Options Menu with OK (otherwise the latest changes won't be saved)
3. Open Tools -> Options again and go to Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General
4. Click "Generate .editorconfig file from settings" on the top
5. If not saved with .editorconfig file name directly, move it there. I personally only select the relevant (i.e. those changed by me) settings from the generated file and move them over.

Note that although the local rule does not work when only set up in the GUI menu, the .editorconfig created from it is perfectly working. So you might still use the GUI for "design" of rules if you prefer.